# Pareto Distribution with parameters α and β: Prove that the variance does not exist if β≤2.

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, variance

A Pareto distribution with a pdf:

$f(x)=βα^β/x^(β+1), α<x<∞, α>0,β>0$

Note:$x$ to the power of $(β+1)$.

I estimated the mean and variance to be:
$EX=αβ/(β-1)$, $Var X=(βα^2)/((β-2) (β-1)^2)$

What is the proof that if $β<2$, variance does not exist? I really would like to understand this point.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For $\beta\le 2$ the variance you calculated becomes first infinite and then even negative. Is that possible ?

Comment: No, because it is a sum of squares. I think I now get it! Thank you so much!